# How to add a 'Done' button to iOS Keyboard [ Webview / Phonegap / Cordova ]

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, webview

When editing a HTML `textarea`, the main (iPad) keyboard has Previous / Next buttons above it, but no Done button like in native apps.

Since many users are unfamiliar with the Resign button near the space bar, is there a way to make the Done button appear?

Answer (score 1):

You can change caption of keyboard  key using this method in UITextView or UITextField:

```
 [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];
```

or change property in Interface Builder [Text Input Traits]->[Return Key];

Answer (score 0):

you can add the view at the top of the keyboard as such.

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] init];//Put your view here.
```

commonly it is a toolbar that is put in there. but you should be able to put whatever view you want.